# Can someone explain how this function works pls ? i didnt get this code : nums.map { |n| factors(n) }.inject(:&)

Tags: ruby

```
def factors(num)
  (1..num).select { |i| num % i == 0}
end


def mutual_factors(*nums)
  nums.map { |n| factors(n) }.inject(:&)
end
```

I cant understand this part `nums.map { |n| factors(n) }.inject(:&)`

Comment: `[a, b, c].inject(:&)` is equivalent to `a & b & c`. If the objects are arrays, it, returns those elements that are present in all arrays. (see [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#method-i-26))

Answer (score 3):

`nums.map { |n| factors(n) }` returns an array of factors for each element in `nums`.

`.inject(:&)` calculates the intersection (common elements) between each array of factors.

For example,

```
irb(main):013:0> [2,4,10].map {|n| factors(n)}
=> [[1, 2], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5, 10]]
irb(main):014:0> [[1, 2], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5, 10]].inject(:&)
=> [1, 2]
```